# How to mount an external volume to Docker container? OS X

Tags: macos, docker

Trying to mount an external volume on my mac (10.13) to a docker container.

I have a volume mounted: `/Volumes/myvolume`

I am trying to mount it to a docker container:

`docker run -t --rm -v /Volumes/myvolume/foo:/opt/myvolume busybox ls /opt/myvolume`

Prints nothing. If I change it to something on my default disk it works fine:
`docker run -t --rm -v /Users/Steve/foo:/opt/myvolume busy box ls /opt/myvolume`
Shows me my files.

Also, if I just mount the volume I can see the foo folder, but it's empty.

```
docker run -it --rm -v /Volumes/myvolume busybox
/ # cd /opt/myvolume
/ ls
/ foo
/ cd foo
/ ls
/
```

I've tried restarting docker. Going to try playing with different volume/mount types next..

UPDATE: It works fine on my colleagues machine! He is running 10.12 so hasn't upgraded yet. Maybe this has something to do with APFS in 10.13? I tried creating volumes of different filetypes to see if I could find one that worked, but none did :(

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, Docker for Mac does not allow to bind any volume to a docker container. In Docker's Preferences, there is a section "File Sharing" in which you can specify which directories (and their subdirectories) can be bound to containers:

[image: sample configuration for Docker Mac file sharing]

The documentation link in the screenshot leads to the following [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces).

Comment: But `/Volumes` is there by default, which means `-v /Volumes/myvolume/foo:/opt/myvolume` should work?

Comment: I manually added /Volumes/myvolume/foo in addition to /Volumes in the docker file sharing setup. After this, docker compose mounting error disappeared. But, i have some operation not permitted error logs inside my docker container. I guess I need to do some additional perm set up.